# How to append all spreadsheets in the same folder?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to append all spreadsheets from the same folder to a master sheet.

I have found a similar code here but I can append the spreadsheets only when the master sheet is also in the selected folder. How could it be modified so that it could be able to applicable to other folders?please advise~

```
function appendData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1UQ5J3xdNnqyHvC-CJ1vAu5YPSxq9Sya9");
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var cnt=0;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    cnt++;
    // if the file is not a Sheet, skip it
    if (file.getMimeType() != "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet") {
      continue;
    }

    var importSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId())
    // assuming you only want to append the first sheet of each Spreadsheet:
    var range = importSheet.getSheets()[0].getDataRange();

    // extend the main sheet if you need to:
    try {
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows() + range.getNumRows(), 1);
    }
    catch (e) {
      sheet.insertRowsAfter(sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows(), range.getNumRows() + 1);
    }    
    // remove the headers from the data to copy:    
    range = importSheet.getSheets()[0].getRange(2, 1, range.getNumRows() - 1, range.getNumColumns())

    // copy the data:
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows() + 1, 1, range.getNumRows(), range.getNumColumns()).setValues(range.getValues());    
  }
}
```

Comment: Please differentiate carefully between `sheet` and `spreadsheet`. The code you provided will append the data from the FIRST sheet of a ll spreadsheets in a given folder to the ACTIVE sheet - the active sheet of the spreadsheet to which your script is bound. It should correctly no matter in which folder the spreadsheet containing the active sheet is located (unless you have permission issues). But maybe it is not exactly this what you are trying to do? Please explain more in detail and provide the errors you get.

Comment: @ziganotschka, thanks for clarifying. yes, this code is logically correct and there is no problem of permission issue. 
However, there are no any response when I run this script in script editor. In my script, there is a demo folder ID but I cannot append those spreadsheet somehow. Do you see any problem from this script making it not workable?

Comment: I don't see any problems with the code (unless a sheet contains less than two rows - in this case you will get an error). Which error do you encounter if your master sheet is not in the same folder? Is the `demo folder ID` the Id of a folder on your drive? And does this folder contain Google spreadsheet files?

Comment: @ziganotschka, I find the problem is that this script is only applicable to google sheets but not excel files, which mean when a folder contains Google sheets and Excel files, it can only append the google files. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Your code contains `file.getMimeType() != "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"`, so it works only for Google Sheets. If you have want to do it with Excel files, you need to convert them into Google Sheets first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function appendData() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById("1UQ5J3xdNnqyHvC-CJ1vAu5YPSxq9Sya9");
  var files=folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var importSheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId())
    var values=importSheet.getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);    
    Logger.log(file.getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: may I know is there any way that this script could be able to append Excel files in the google folder as well?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Excel files.  This is Google Sheets not Excel.

Answer (score 0):

### Append both spreadsheets and Excel files to the same master sheet

If you need to append not only sheets from Google spreadsheets, but also form Excel files, you need to convert the latter ones to Google Sheets first.

For this, you can modify your existing code as following:

```
function appendData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1fUpTphVpYGfLv6SjWxZdbcIK7PHCZOnt");
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var cnt=0;
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    cnt++;
    // if the file is an excel - convert it to sheet    
    if (file.getMimeType() != "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet") {
      Logger.log(file.getMimeType());
//here is the additional part
//define here mime-types of interest and convert them
      if (file.getMimeType() == "application/vnd.ms-excel" || file.getMimeType() == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") {
        var fileId = file.getId();
        var folderId = folder.getId();
        var blob = file.getBlob();
        var resource = {
          title: file.getName(),
          mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
          parents: [{id: folderId}],
        };      
        var file = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob);
      }else{
        continue;
      }
    }      
    var importSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId())
    // assuming you only want to append the first sheet of each Spreadsheet:
    var range = importSheet.getSheets()[0].getDataRange();

    // extend the main sheet if you need to:
    try {
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows() + range.getNumRows(), 1);
    }
    catch (e) {
      sheet.insertRowsAfter(sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows(), range.getNumRows() + 1);
    }    
    // remove the headers from the data to copy:  

    range = importSheet.getSheets()[0].getRange(2, 1, range.getNumRows() - 1, range.getNumColumns())
    Logger.log("range.getA1Notation():" + range.getA1Notation());
    // copy the data:
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows() + 1, 1, range.getNumRows(), range.getNumColumns()).setValues(range.getValues());    
  }
}
```